# Does C# support "Generic inheritance" and how/why?

Tags: c#, templates, generics, inheritance, dynamic

I want to declare something similar to this:

```
public class ImpostorClassWithAddedNotificationSupport<T> : T, ICustomTypeProvider, INotifyPropertyChanged where T : class
```

But I receive this error:

> CS0689: Cannot derive from 'T' because it is a type parameter

I would like to dynamically add new behavior to properties (overwrite base class properties) with my class. Each property of my class would call base class property then add notification to it. I would also add more functionalities (methods). This way, everything would works fine in design but have additional functionality to the derived class. It is a kind of impersonation (impostor) to add more functionalities.

Is there a way to dynamically overwrite a type in order to add functionalities (functionality like for example Notification)? If yes, how? If no, why?

**My initial intention is:**

I try to do a FakeObject that mimics any object I'd like to edit. It would dynamically create all properties of any object it mimics. Then I could edit that "FakeObject" and if I want to cancel, I flush that fakeObject and my original object has never been modified (like a "Cancel" on any dialog). On "Ok", it would apply changes to the original object. It already works for a PropertyGrid because PropertyGrid use reflection behind to discover and read/write properties. But I want to use my class at design time with [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) and [WinUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_UI_Library). The notification part is only a bonus that would come with it. Otherwise I have to write a "Copy constructor" or any similar copy mechanism    and also I have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on each and every classes. I would prefer to keep my classes "Plain" - [POCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object). I would saved all of that if I would be able to write my code as intended.

**What I realise after I asked**

It is not possible actually. I should ask Microsoft for a new feature.

Comment: This can't work because to derive from `T`, you should first describe the shape of `T`. But I can't understand the goal you are trying to achieve. Can you provide an example, please?

Comment: I cannot provide an example because it wouldn't compile. But, if I would be able to do that, then by overriding the class descriptor and override methods and properties (using dynamically the  "new" keyword) , I would be able to add behaviors transparently to any classes. It already works using a "PropertyGrid" because a property Grid adapt itself from the Metadata (reflection) behinds to discover the class but I would like to have the same functionality as using ICustomTypeProvider but at design time while declaring my WPF or WInUI interface. Having Roslyn running, I think it could be done.

Comment: When seeing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface here. Do you had hopes you would then somehow generically get the usage of INotifyPropertyChanged  into every property of T then?

Comment: @Ralf, Yes, the generic derived class would be able to override all properties and add notification behavior to all of them. IT would then let the base class "plain".

Comment: @SwiftSharp, It need to be derived in order to have access to all properties of base class at design time. For example to continue to be able to do bindings in WPF or WinUI. (the compiler should know where to find methods and properties in both places)

Comment: Yes, I understand it wouldn't compile. Just wanted to see a code snippet to get your intention or at least a pseudo code. Have you checked [C# Source Generators](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/source-generator-for-inotifypropertychanged) or [Static Abstracts in Interfaces](https://dunnhq.com/posts/2021/generic-math/#static-abstracts-in-interfaces)? It may be helpful.

Comment: code weavers such as [postsharp](https://doc.postsharp.net/inotifypropertychanged) and [fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) can do this for you

Comment: @Arthur, I try to do a FakeObject that mimics any objects. It would dynamically create all properties of any object it mimics. Then I could edit that "FakeObject" and if I want to cancel, I flush that fakeObject and my original object has never been modified (like a "Cancel" on any dialog). On "Ok", it would apply changes. IT already works for a PropertyGrid because PropertyGrid use refelection behind to discover and read/write properties. But I want to use my class at design time with WPF and WinUI. THe notification part is only a bonus that would come with it.

Comment: @qujck, I'm not sure about it. PostSharp does preprocessing. But I need to have access to  access to a class before it has been preprocessed. The compile should know it at deisgn time to help me design me interface. It should be compatible with the designer/IDE. IT should be part of the language I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this cannot be implemented this way, as the compiler error indicates.  Basically, generics let you write a class around that generic type without knowing much about it, except for maybe the constraints you put on it like where T : class.  So it’s too many unknowns for the compiler.  Keep in mind, a generic class can use generic types from things not in its assembly, like how List<Foo> where List is in a MS assembly and Foo is in your custom assembly.  Base classes need to be in a visible assembly to the derived class when it’s compiled.

You can see the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0689) or a Microsoft blog post [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090814-00/?p=17093).

It’s good question, though.  These types of questions really help flesh out the understanding of C# and OO and where its capabilities and limits are.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply not possible in .NET.

Since you have no idea what `T` is you could not override any methods, nor call any methods on it. If you add an interface constraint to give you that possibility, you could just inherit from that interface instead and create a regular decorator.

So I assume you would want some kind of template to wrap each method from the type you want to decorate, to provide things like logging. And this concept would likely need significant changes in the IL format and runtime to support.

A possible workaround would be to use reflection to emit a new type dynamically at runtime. Another could be to use annotations to rewrite the IL code in an assembly to add additional functionality to methods. I believe this is the approach used by [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/).

Answer (score 0):

So what you actually want is something like this:

```
MyClass x = new AddNotificationSupport<MyClass>();
```

When `AddNotificationSupport<>` implements decorator or proxy (never understood the difference between two). I think your best way to go is [Castle.DynamicProxy](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dynamicproxy.md) project. Here is a great tutorial to learn how it works and what you can do with it: https://kozmic.net/dynamic-proxy-tutorial/

**Update:**
Following your edit to the question. You can [Mixin](https://kozmic.net/2009/08/12/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial-part-xiii-mix-in-this-mix/) some `ChangeTracker` class with the original class. Then implement an interceptor to decorate the required methods and properties. The `ChangeTracker` class should "remember" all the changes applied on the proxy and provide the ability to revert them by calling the `Cancel` extension method.

This code may help you to start:

```
public static T AsTrackable<T>(this T target)
    where T : class
{
    if (target == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (target is ITrackableObject)
    {
        return target;
    }

    var options = new ProxyGenerationOptions { Hook = new TrackableHook() };
    options.AddMixinInstance(new TrackableObject());
    var interceptor = new TrackSettersInterceptor();

    var result = (T)_proxyGenerator.CreateClassProxyWithTarget(
        typeof(T),
        new[] { typeof(ITrackableObject) },
        target,
        options,
        interceptor);

    return result;
}
```

You need to implement the `TrackableObject`, `TrackableHook` and `TrackSettersInterceptor`.

Comment: The class really need to be inherited in order to be usable at design time to define Bindings. Actually, what I see in your proposed answer, there is no inheritance.

Comment: The power of dynamic proxies is that they are actually inherit from the original object. You can create an extension method that will create a proxy and the usage will be like this: `MyClass x = new MyClass().AsTrackable()` for a new instance or `MyClass x = myClass.AsTrackable()` for an existing one.

Comment: In documention of kozmic it is written: "You obviously can’t proxy a sealed class, since it can’t be inherited from. You can only override virtual methods, so for non-virtual methods there’s nothing you can gain". I do not want to impact my base class. They should stay the same. IT is really an impostor I need.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, there is no magic solution. When using Source Generators, the class must be `partial`. For dynamic proxies, it should be non-sealed with virtual properties.

Comment: I would suggest exploring design patterns a bit, like decorator.  Gang of Four is the gold standard, but I think Head First Design Patterns book is probably the most approachable and fun on this topic.  https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-design/0596007124/

Comment: @DanCsharpster you can't create generic decorator that will work with all types. You will have to create them one by one writing a lot of boilerplate code.